# Converting a SQL Server 2016 JSON dump with emojis from UTF-16LE to UTF-8

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery, iconv

I am dumping tables from a SQL Server 2016 instance with `bcp` - using [this method](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/02/09/exporting-tables-from-sql-server-in-json-line-delimited-format-using-bcp-exe/) to generate newline delimited json exports. These files are encoded as UTF-16LE, but to import them into BigQuery I need to convert them to UTF-8.

Using `iconv -f utf-16le -t UTF-8 table.json > table.utf8.json` works in 99% of the cases - but I am stumbling over emojis in the files (from user input in a web form). Some of them cannot be converted and iconv errors out with:
`iconv: table.json:39972:807: cannot convert`
Checking the file yields some emojis and some undefined chars: [image]

Deleting those chars, lets iconv finish the job: [image]

How can I either export valid UTF-8 from SQL-Server or convert the resulting files into UTF-8 if I want to keep the emojis? Is it possible that SQL Server stores incorrectly encoded chars?

My current workaround is to use the `-c` switch of iconv, to discard these characters silently.

**Update:**
This is the current script to extract the JSON files from SQL Server:

```
set @cmd ='bcp "select  '
IF @top is not null 
  set @cmd = @cmd +' top('+@top+') '

IF @startdate is  null    
  BEGIN
    set @filename = (SELECT replace(@currenttable,'.','_'))
    set @cmd = @cmd + '(select '+@header+' for json path, '
    set @cmd = @cmd+ ' without_array_wrapper) from DWH.'+@currenttable+' " queryout Z:\json\'+@filename+'.json -a65535 -w  -T  -S SRV\DWH -d DWH'
  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN
    set @filename = (SELECT replace(replace(replace(@currenttable,']',''),'[',''),'.','_')+'_'+@currentdateid)
    set @cmd = @cmd + '(select '+@header+' for json path, '
    set @cmd = @cmd+ 'without_array_wrapper) from DWH.'+@currenttable+' where '+@partitioncolumn+'>= '''+@startdate+''''
    set @cmd = @cmd+ ' AND '+@partitioncolumn+'< '''+@enddate+'''"'
    set @cmd = @cmd+ ' queryout Z:\json\'+@filename+'.json -a65535 -w  -T  -S SRV -d DWH'
  END 

exec xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output
```

Comment: To answer one of your questions: yes, SQL Server can store code points that don't map to characters, invalid surrogate sequences and what have you. Internally its `NCHAR` type can hold any 16-bit value, and whether a sequence of code points forms valid characters only becomes an issue when the collation gets involved (comparing it with literals and suchlike). However, this is more of a GIGO issue -- SQL Server will not screw up the encoding itself. If you want to get down to it, use `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ...)` on suspect columns to see what bytes are in them.

Comment: What's your `bcp` command line? `bcp -C 65001` should export directly as UTF-8, but specifically for `CHAR` data, and I'm not sure how that interacts with the Unicode data produced by `FOR JSON`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I've added the command line